# communication between two objects

Tags: javascript

I have two objects, I hope to establish the communication between the two objects.
Is there a common way to do this?
Of course, I know I can invoke the method of two objects.
Is there any other way?

Your comment welcome

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what you want to accomplish. It's unclear what "communication between two objects" means to you.

Comment: I have little to no idea what you mean by "communication" between objects. I'm sorry, but you need to be clearer - perhaps a code example might help.

Comment: @arachide Web clients and servers can communicate via either HTTP/[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) or [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets). The objects won't be able to "*talk*" to each other directly, but the requests and responses could be based on the state of those objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much context for what you want soooo...

```
var ob = function(){

};
ob.prototype.func = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
ob.prototype.setPartner = function(obj){
    this.partner = obj;
};
ob.prototype.comm = function(){
    this.partner.func("data");
};
var o1 = new ob();
var o2 = new ob();
o1.setPartner(o2);
o2.setPartner(o1);
o1.comm();
```

PS this will create circlular objects